# Perform action after push notification when app is killed : react-native, IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios, expo

Working on an IOS react-native project.

When the app is DEAD and a push notifications is received -

I want the app to navigate to another page based on the notification's payload.
When the app is in foreground or background - everything works just fine.
when the app is killed - the app just opens itself.

added below is my Appdelegate.m code. 
I am catching the notification and log it to the console, but I don't know how to send it to react-native.

using RN 0.46

expo 19 (detached to ExpoKit)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    _window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [[ExpoKit sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    _rootViewController = [ExpoKit sharedInstance].rootViewController;
    _window.rootViewController = _rootViewController;

    [_rootViewController loadReactApplication];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];


    if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]) {
          NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
          if (notification) {
              //logs the notification's payload
              NSLog(@"app recieved notification from remote%@",notification);
          } else {
              NSLog(@"app did not recieve notification");
          }

    }

    return YES;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nirbenya/pxojj7qv/

Answer (score 0):

To achieve such behavior you need to implement some sort of [deep linking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) for your app. This way you can listen for payload in your react-native app and navigate to correct screen. [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/linking#Deep-Linking) and [react-native-navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/deep-links) have their own implementations for deep linking.

From react-native docs,

> **Handling deep links**
>
> If your app was launched from an external url registered to your app
>   you can access and handle it from any component you want with

```
componentDidMount() {
  Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
    if (url) {
      console.log('Initial url is: ' + url);
    }
  }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my app wasn't launched from an external url. it was launched

Comment: @NirBen-Yair what service are you using for sending notifications?

Comment: normal PushNotificationsIOS that comes with react-native. nothing custom like one signal or firebase. I also ejected from expo and I think it might be related.

Comment: Then you should continue implementing `PushNotificationIOS` API and use [`addEventListener`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#addeventlistener)